# What is the benefit of stopping the users from creating copy of objects of the class, but allow the dynamic ones?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

This is more about C++ rather than qt.

The following works:

```
m_QPushButton_calibration = new QPushButton("Calibrate", this);
connect(m_QPushButton_calibration, SIGNAL (released()),this, SLOT (handleButton()));
```

But for this one,

```
QPushButton tion = QPushButton("Cte", this);
connect(tion, SIGNAL (released()),this, SLOT (handleButton()));
```

the compiler says:

```
/opt/Qt5.5/5.5-static/include/QtWidgets/qpushbutton.h:96: error: 'QPushButton::QPushButton(const QPushButton&)' is private
     Q_DISABLE_COPY(QPushButton)

                ^
```

I want to understand the use case for this.

**What is the benefit of stopping the users from creating copy of objects of the class, but allow the dynamic ones?**

Comment: 1. You're probably not making a static object. 2. It is about things being copyable or not, not "dynamic vs whatever".

Comment: Why not just `QPushButton tion("Cte", this);` ? That should work even if copy constructor is marked private.

Comment: The class may be non-copyable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't stop you from creating automatic object, but from making copy of it which you do with:

```
QPushButton tion = QPushButton("Cte", this);
```

`tion` is a copy of the temporary `QPushButton("Cte", this)`.

Further explanation is given here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator

Nothing is stopping you from initializing it directly:

```
QPushButton tion("Cte", this);
```

But this button will be destroyed when you'll leave the scope it is declared in contrary to the allocated one.

I'd advise you to use new connect syntax to get compiler errors instead of runtime errors:

```
connect(tion, &QPushButton::released, this, &YourClass::handleButton);
```

Comment: thanks, why is it stopping me from making a copy of it?

Comment: @AquariusTheGirl QPushButton is part of QObject hierarchy and as such must have entity semantic to avoid memery and slicing issues.

Comment: @AquariusTheGirl The reason why is explain in Qt documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that class has a disabled copy constructor. That doesn't mean objects of that class aren't allowed to have automatic or static storage duration. It just means you need to use direct initialization:

```
QPushButton tion("Cte", this);
```

In C++17, your original code will become well-formed due to guaranteed copy elision.